# 11ty - deploy /public folder on github pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nunjucks, eleventy

i'm a junior front end developer..  I have recently created a blog site using 11ty, Nunjucks, and Netlify CMS. I am now trying to deploy this site on GitHub Pages, but I am facing challenges as the index file for my site is located in the /public folder. This is different from the default configuration for GitHub Pages deployment which typically deploys the site from the root folder of the repository. I have tried searching online for a solution to this issue, but most of the information I have found seems to be outdated.

Is there a way to modify the configuration of GitHub Pages to deploy my site from the /public folder? could you please provide detailed instructions on how to accomplish this? I would greatly appreciate any guidance. thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- add ".nojekyll" empty file at the root of the project folder
- add a scripts command in your package.json file to run eleventy:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "eleventy"
},
```

- add a workflow file in this path: ".github/workflows/" for example: https://github.com/jdsteinbach/intro-11ty-slides/blob/main/.github/workflows/eleventy_build.yml
- create a deploy key to use actions: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-pages-action#%EF%B8%8F-create-ssh-deploy-key

Some other help:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/eleventy-github-pages-lea-tortay/
https://www.rockyourcode.com/how-to-deploy-eleventy-to-github-pages-with-github-actions/

A bit easier to deploy on Netlify, even because you mentioned NetlifyCMS, so i recommned using Netlify instead of GHpages.

I hope it helps.